# angular2: how to HTTP request a JSON file based on the id from another JSON file

Tags: json, angular

What is the best way to use a HTTP request to get a JSON file from an ID of another JSON file? Should I pass the ID from one service to another and use that ID to grab the JSON file from there. Or would it be better to have a single service that passes the id from one request to another and returns the second JSON from there? How would I go about implement something like this?

```
  getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.projectsUrl)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getProject(id: string): Observable<Project> {
    return this.getProjects()
      .map(projects => projects.find(project => project.id === id));
  }

  getGallery(): Observable<Gallery[]> {
    return this.getProjects()
    .map(projects => projects.find(project => project.id === id)); // Retrieve the current page id
    // use the id down here to call this.http.get(data/galleries/:id.JSON)
  }
```

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `mergeMap()` instead of `map()` if `find()` also is an `Observable`.